# Launching multiple urls in firefox from python3

Tags: python, firefox, browser, python-3.x

i am trying to lunch multiple urls from a text file in Firefox via python. i am using win7 OS & python 3. i need some direction to pass the argument to Firefox.

```
import os
import subprocess

f = open ('C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\urls.txt','r')
data = f.read()
print(data)
# i need some help here to pass this argument to Firefox.
f.close()
```

urls.txt

```
http://www.abc.com
http://www.xyz.com/test
http://www.abc.net/test.html
http://www.test.com
http://www.msn.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**`webbrowser` module**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import webbrowser
firefox = webbrowser.get('firefox')
for url in data.split('\n'):
    firefox.open_new_tab(url)
```

If you don't want to enforce a particular browser and just start the default one, use `webbrowser.open_new_tab`.

The `webbrowser` module isn't very reliable, especially on Windows, so you might have to start the process manually using the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
firefox_path = 'C:/Program Files/Firefox/firefox' # change this line accordingly
for url in data.split('\n'):
    subprocess.Popen([firefox_path, url])
```

Also, Firefox supports multiple URLs in the command line, so the following solution is better for it:

```
import subprocess
urls = open('C:/Users/test/Desktop/urls.txt').read().split('\n')
subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files/Firefox/firefox']+urls)
```

Comment: 10x, for the inputs, i am getting trackback for the line#2, http://pastebin.com/msbJuuS8

Comment: @user1582596 It looks like Python can't find Firefox... Try `webbrowser.open_new_tab` without the `firefox = ...` line.

Comment: yeah, now no tracebacks, but have two issue. 1) it fires IE 2) only the last tab is being lunched. _http://pastebin.com/J5feShRB

Comment: also tired with, webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(urls) but no luck. is there any way to hardcode Firefox path.

Comment: very nice, but one glitch, if FF is running, while executing this script, FF returns the following message, "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system."

Comment: 10x for the time, tired all the three variations but somehow it detects as "Firefox is already running, but is not responding"